# Adding trailing zeros to floating decimals

Tags: python, format

I am trying to write some floats numbers as decimals with 14 digit after floating point. So i want to add traling zeros for numbers who have less than 14 digits . however, when I use the folowing, it performs a random approximation rather than adding zeros .

```
print ('%.14f' % 381.949875)
print ('%.14f' % 383.558625 )
print ( '%.14f' % 382.593375)
```

The result is as follows :

```
381.94987500000002
383.55862500000001
382.59337499999998
```

Any clue ?

Comment: It is definitely something related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken as `381.949875 + 0.00000000000001 == 381.949875`. I would have to check in more detail but I suspect that in order to do the print, behind the curtains the first number is added to a very small 15 digit after the decimal number in order to ensure the 0 padding.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this formatting I believe

```py
f"{381.949875:0<14}"
f"{383.558625:0<14}"
f"{382.593375:0<14}"
```

Comment: i want to complete with 14 digits after the floating point , not for all digits